# Date Validation/Open Workbook VBA

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-statements

I have a workbook that I am trying to set up e-mail notifications for whenever the workbook is opened.  One of the ways that I had intended to trigger the notifications is based upon date validation. I am trying to figure out a VBA solution for refreshing the date values of specific cells depending upon the days of the week.  I have one line of 7 cells (each representing Sunday-Saturday) and am trying to figure out a sub that would populate the dates in those cells as they correspond with today's date.  For example, if today = Thursday, the sub would know that TODAY()=05/21/2015 and that is the starting date which would go in cell 5, it could then figure out what the other dates are depending on their distance from 5... Is something like this doable? I had originally worked in a large amount of conditional formulas but it was getting messy trying to handle so many columns with formulas that would check and balance each other that this seemed like a good avenue to pursue...

I am trying to sketch out how the sub would need to look, but I have very little experience in how to reference dates in VBA.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get this into Thisworkbook module

```
private sub workbook_open
Dim dayOfWeek As String
Dim i As Integer

dayOfWeek = Weekday(Date)

Select Case dayOfWeek

Case "1"
For i = 1 To 7
Cells(1, i).Value = Date + i - 1
Next i

Case "2"
For i = 1 To 7

Cells(1, i).Value = Date + i - 2
Next i
Case "3"

For i = 1 To 7
Cells(1, i).Value = Date + i - 3
Next i

Case "4"
For i = 1 To 7
Cells(1, i).Value = Date + i - 4
Next i

Case "5"
For i = 1 To 7
Cells(1, i).Value = Date + i - 5
Next i

Case "6"

For i = 1 To 7
Cells(1, i).Value = Date + i - 6
Next i

Case "7"

For i = 1 To 7
Cells(1, i).Value = Date + i - 7
Next i

End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! If I wanted to make Sunday values = A1, Monday values = B1, Tuesday = C1, etc. would something similar to this code you have listed work for that? I'm thinking I would just need to define what the return_value of the dates are?

Comment: worksheetfunction.weekday(MyDate) ' this will return you the day

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I haven't explained very clearly. So my workspace is 7 columns (A1:G1, Sunday through Saturday) I am hoping to have a dynamic process in which excel checks today's date and (based on what today is) it populates each cell with the date value as it corresponds with today's date... so each time the workbook is opened, today is going to change, but it will know that today = some vbDate value (1-7) and based on what vbDate today is, the other columns would adjust to their respective dates...

Comment: So basicly process should be I open workbook-> it finds out that today is sunday-> it writes the today date in A1 ?

Comment: Exactly. But it would then say, if today = 1 (Sunday) then Monday = x (in B1), Tuesday = x (C1), etc. This way it would keep track of what the dates of the week are and would be easier to build notifications on a rolling basis

Comment: Awesome! This works perfectly! Is there a way that I can keep this function to only happen in Range("Sheet1")? I tried putting in a qualifier "With Sheet1..." and it is giving me a run-time error so I wasn't sure if I should make this a call event and then place this code in the worksheet module or not... You're amazing!

Comment: all you need to do is put sheets("sheet1"). or sheets(1). in front of every cells(1,i) for example sheets(1).cells(1,i).value = ... do not change the code localisation